# Key in Javascript is undefined when it is clearly defined when I print out object in consol

Tags: javascript, variables, object, dictionary, undefined

So I have an object that looks like this:

[image: console]

Clearly it contains two keys "200001" and "201601".

But when I try to access those two variables I get undefined!

Code bellow:

```
        console.warn($rootScope.layout);
        console.log('layout 200001', $rootScope.layout[200001]);
        console.log('layout 201601', $rootScope.layout[201601]);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is probably a quirk of Chrome's console. The first console message might show a later status of the object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays. You can confirm by doing `console.warn(JSON.stringify($rootScope.layout))` to force printing the current status of the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: console.warn(JSON.stringify($rootScope.layout)) shows {} !! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling this code and where do they get defined?

I think they get defined later than the `console.log` is called. When you click/expand the `$rootScope` variable in the chrome console, Chrome re-evaluates the variable then you can see them.

Comment: Correct, when I add console.warn(JSON.stringify($rootScope.layout)), it shows {}